# How to 'array push' a string into a list in TI-Nspire?

Tags: ti-basic

As homework,  I must swap letters in a given string. I already figured out how to do this, but not how to display them at once. it involves a for loop. so if I include disp x in the for loop, it displays them between parentheses and a space, but I want them all together, so instead of

"a"

"b"

"c"

I want "abc". Is there a way to do this? Should I push the variable into an array and then display the array after the for loop? How to push variables in to an array?

This is in TI-Nspire CX Cas btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an element `x` to an array `A` use `augment(A, {x})`.

For your specific case, I would use a string variable (call it `string`) to which I concatenate the next letter at each iteration of the `for` loop.  So if the next letter to be added is in the variable `letter`, you would put the following line of code at the end of your `for` loop: `string := string & letter`.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know the concatenator syntax.

Answer (score 1):

here is also way:

Local array
array[dim(array)+1] := value

Comment: I think this is better than `augment`

Answer (score 0):

I would answer you by an example covering your scenario. Let's say we are aiming to have a array listing the elements of binaries when we construct an integer into the base2 (binary).

```
Define LibPub develope(a,b)=
Func
Local mi,m,q
mi:=mod(a,b)
q:=((a-mi)/(b))
Disp mi
While q≥b
  a:=q
  m:=mod(a,b)
  q:=((a-m)/(b))
  Disp m
EndWhile
EndFunc
```

The above small program develops an integer in decimal base into the binary base; however each binary is shown in a separate line as you mentioned:
ex:

```
develope(222,2)
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mzNO.jpg)

but this is not what you want, you want is in a single line. **IMPORTANCE IS THAT YOU SHOULD LIKELIHOOD WANT EACH ELEMENT BE ACCESSIBLE AS A SEPARATE INTEGER, RIGHT? LIKE AS AN ELEMENT IN A ARRAY LIST, THAT'S WHAT YOU LOOKING FOR RIGHT?**

There we Go:

```
    Define LibPub develope(n,b)=
Func
Local q,k,seti,set,valid
valid:=b
If valid>1 Then
  q:=n
  k:=0
  set:={}
While q≠0
    seti:=mod(q,b)
    q:=int(((q)/(b)))
    k:=k+1
    seti→set[k]
EndWhile
Else
  Disp "Erreur, La base doit être plus grand que 1."
EndIf
Return set
EndFunc
```

Basically, because we do not know how many elements are going to be added in the array list, the `set:={}` declares an array with an undefined `dim` (typically length) in order that dynamically be augmented.

The command `seti→set[k]` will add the value of the `seti` whatever it is, into the `k` position of the array list.

and the `return set` simply returns the array.

if you need to get access to a specific element, you know how to to that: `elementNumber5:=set[5]`

I wish it helps.